# Asterisk - use custom functions

Tags: odbc, asterisk, freetds

My Asterisk can write Call Data Record and channel event logging use freetds.
I know, that for my question i can use func_odbc. But my linux knowledge is low. I can use custom dialplan function without func_odbc. Maybe "func_tds"?

Comment: Very hard to imagine what you trying to ask. Are you asking if there is func_tds? Definitly - no, it not needed to anyone. But you can write if you need.

Comment: @arheops I can use func_odbc if I'm CDR and CEL does not use odbc and uses freetds? Or you need to use one tool to work with the database?

Comment: You can use odbc driver(freetds) and func_odbc. I not see what is relation to cdr. Anyway BETTER use odbc, it MUCH MORE tested code

Comment: @arheops thx, that's exactly what I did

Comment: @arheops Can I use CDR and CEL simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem. Not recommended use odbc &mysql cdrs at same time(sometimes go conflict). If you use same db driver, should be no problem. You even can write both CEL and CDRs into more then one db at same time.

Comment: @arheops I'm using cdr_adaptive_odbc and cel_odbc. CDR Works - CEL no

Comment: CDR and CEL definitly work if configure propertly on same box. you have debug your detup. debug is offtopic here.